# What exactly is happening in the recursive calls involved?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

So, I was trying to solve the following problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/MREPLBRC/en/

A regular bracket sequence is a string of characters consisting only of opening and closing brackets, and satisfying the following conditions:

• An empty string is a regular bracket sequence.

• If A is a regular bracket0sequence, then (A), [A] and {A} are also regular bracket sequences.

• If A and B are regular bracket sequences, then AB is also a regular bracket sequence.

For example, the sequences [({})], {} i {}[{}] are regular, but the sequences [({{([, } and [{}])([{}] are not.

Ivica has found a string which looks like it could be a regular bracket sequence. Some of the characters have become smudged and illegible, and could have been any character.

Write a program that calculates how many ways the illegible characters in the string can be replaced by brackets so that the result is a regular bracket sequence. This number can be very large, so output only its last 5 digits.

Input

The first line contains an even integer N (2 <= N <= 200), the length of the string.

The second line contains the string. Illegible characters are represented by the '?' character.

Output

Output the number of regular bracket sequences the string could have read.

After much thinking, I couldn't really form a solution for this, and hence, I tried to look upon the solution. I found it here: http://ruhinraihan.blogspot.in/2012/08/spoj-4038-counting-way-of-bracket.html

Here is the code for this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<sstream>
#include<cctype>
#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<stack>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#include<iomanip>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;

#define INF (1<<29)
#define SET(a) memset(a,-1,sizeof(a))
#define ALL(a) a.begin(),a.end()
#define CLR(a) memset(a,0,sizeof(a))
#define FILL(a,v) memset(a,v,sizeof(a))
#define PB push_back
#define FOR(i,n) for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
#define PI acos(-1.0)
#define EPS 1e-9
#define MP(a,b) make_pair(a,b)
#define READ(f) freopen(f, "r", stdin)
#define WRITE(f) freopen(f, "w", stdout)
#define LL long long
#define MOD 100000

bool moduloUsed;
LL memo[200+10][200+10];
string s;

LL func(int left, int right)
{
    int i, valid;
    if(left>right)  return 1;

    if(memo[left][right]!=-1)   return memo[left][right];

    LL ret=0;

    for(i=left+1;i<=right;i+=2)
    {
        if(s[left]=='(' && s[i]==')') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='{' && s[i]=='}') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='[' && s[i]==']') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='?' && s[i]==')') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='?' && s[i]=='}') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='?' && s[i]==']') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='(' && s[i]=='?') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='{' && s[i]=='?') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='[' && s[i]=='?') valid=1;
        else if(s[left]=='?' && s[i]=='?') valid=3;
        else    valid=0;

        ret+=valid*func(left+1,i-1)*func(i+1,right);

        if(ret>MOD)
        {
            moduloUsed=true;
            ret%=MOD;
        }
    }
return memo[left][right]=ret;
}


int main()
{
    LL ans,length;

    while(cin>>length>>s)
    {
        SET(memo);
        ans=func(0,length-1);
        if(!moduloUsed)
        cout<<ans<<endl;
        else
        printf("%05lld\n",ans);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I want to know, what exactly is happening in the function `fun`. I understood that it is traversing over the input string, and check for possible combinations of balanced parentheses conditions, however, then, `func(left+1,i-1)*func(i+1,right)`, what do these two recursive calls represent? Please help me.

Comment: But are you also aware that there's a [switch/case](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) statement in C and C++?

Comment: @decltype_auto, why do you ask about switch/case here? It is possible to rewrite this code another way (with `switch`), but it will not help Harry to understand the logic of this code.

Comment: Ok, @HarryLewis, since you understand [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), you have everything for understanding this program: in the line `valid*func(left+1,i-1)*func(i+1,right)` there is a multiplication of quantities of possible cases. So, in the `for` loop the program calculates the sum of these products for all possible cuts of the interval [left, right].

Comment: I figured that multiplication thing, but what does, `func(left+1,i-1)` represents specifically? I figured `func(i+1,right)` which basically means, we are doing it for the next position. Also, why are we incrementing `i` by 2 units? Why not just `1`?

Comment: @Ilja And that forecast comes from dice rolls, or right from your crystal ball?

Comment: @decltype_auto, no offense but it would be much helpful to me if you stop showing off to others how knowledgeable you are and help me instead. It's because of people like you, that often many beginners fail to learn because of your attempts to show your amazing humour which believe me, is not so amazing at all.

Comment: @HarryLewis This first I do when I have to understand someone else's  code found on the net is re-format and partly re-formulate it to suit the needs of an expressive programming style. E.g having s[left] and s[i] at one place would be a improve readbility; `func` is not exactly a mnemonic, and 'valid' would be a nice name for a `bool` but not for an int here. You get the idea?

Comment: @decltype_auto, I do, but then, instead, of saying things that won't really prove helpful to anyone, you should let your answer (which helps the OP) do the talking I feel. Instead of saying that it would help readability, write an answer that shows that it will improve readability. And if it does, I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @HarryLewis SO is not a free code writing service. I'm confident you can easily pick up my suggestions and do the work yourself.

Comment: @decltype_auto, oh my god. This is so amazing. You yourself suggested that the code needs to be restructured, and now you yourself are saying that SO is not a code writing service. Atleast look at the question what I asked about. I never asked you to write the code for me. I just asked you to help me with the logic. Keep your head in one thing atleast.

Comment: @HarryLewis: you don't seriously expect help when you behave that way, or do you?

Comment: @decltype_auto, IIya, atleast tried to help unlike you when you were too busy comment on the crystal balls. And no, don't need your help if you don't want to. I believe the community has better people than you who won't mind helping a person in need.

Comment: @HarryLewis: As you may take it from the huge number of answers (1 in six hours), those `better people` (your phrasing, not mine) are eager to help you .  Bonne chance, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer is reached by multiplying all the valid combinations of any open + close bracket pair. The long winded if statement is the stop condition for the recursive function, as any pair can have either 0,1 or 3 valid combinations.  The recursive call that throws you off is actually (combined with the for loop) scanning the entire string for bracket pairs. Had the string been said to be symetrical, it would have been a simpler call: `fun(left + 1, right -1)`

Comment: what does, func(left+1,i-1) represents specifically? I figured func(i+1,right) which basically means, we are doing it for the next position. Also, why are we incrementing i by 2 units? Why not just 1?

Comment: `func(left+1, i-1)` is the substring starting at the left, the other is the substring ending on the right.  They overlap only for the full string

Comment: Actually, I think a better phrasing would be that one treats ? chars as opening brackets and the other as closing. I hope I'm not mistaken.